# How to add a color to 3D surface in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I'm trying to create something with 3D, never used this feature before. I'm trying to change the grey surface to a gradient. How can it be done?

This is what I'm looking at

[image] 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a Symbol for your gradient (just a rectangle with the gradient applied will do fine). You can then apply your symbol to one of the object surfaces using <kbd>Map Art...</kbd> in the 3D Extrude & Bevel Options.

Use <kbd>Scale to Fit</kbd> to stretch the gradient to the correct size of the suface. You'll have to do this for every surface on your shape.

[image]

[image: a gradient applied to the sides]

Comment: Ahh yes, the ever tasteful rainbow gradient :)